# Can't compile std::reduce call, while std::accumulate call compiles on the same arguments

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I've been trying to use `c++17`'s `std::reduce` algorithm. Supposedly, it should support the same APIs supported by `std::accumulate`, but when compiling both in `clang++-9.0` and `gcc-9.2` with `--std=c++17`, the call to `std::accumulate` compiles successfully, and the call to `std::reduce` doesn't.

I tried a couple of things so far:

- Defining the `lambda` both inside and outside of the call
- Specifying explicitly the types with `std::reduce<...>` syntax
- Using the overloads with execution policy parameters

  - Got errors on `#include <execution>`

The following is a sample code that uses `std::reduce` and `std::accumulate` to sum the lengths of strings in a `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    auto op = [](auto acc, auto val) {
        return acc + val.size();
    };
    std::vector<std::string> v = {"a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd"};
    int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);
    int b = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails, in the line calling to `std::reduce` with the following output from `clang-9.0.0`:

```
<source>:12:13: error: no matching function for call to 'reduce'

    int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);

            ^~~~~~~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:26:1: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator' ('__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> *, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >' vs. 'int')

reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Tp __init);

^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:21:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 4 were provided

reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Tp __init,

^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:31:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided

reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);

^

1 error generated.
```

and the following output from `gcc-9.2`:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:12:50: error: no matching function for call to 'reduce(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, int, main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>&)'

   12 |     int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);

      |                                                  ^

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/numeric:229,

                 from <source>:5:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:21:1: note: candidate: 'template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, _ForwardIterator2> std::reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)'

   21 | reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Tp __init,

      | ^~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:21:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:12:50: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator' ('__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' and 'int')

   12 |     int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);

      |                                                  ^

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/numeric:229,

                 from <source>:5:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:26:1: note: candidate: 'template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, _ForwardIterator2> std::reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Tp)'

   26 | reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Tp __init);

      | ^~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:26:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:12:50: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator' ('__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' and 'int')

   12 |     int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);

      |                                                  ^

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/numeric:229,

                 from <source>:5:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:31:1: note: candidate: 'template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _ForwardIterator> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, typename std::iterator_traits<_II>::value_type> std::reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator)'

   31 | reduce(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);

      | ^~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:31:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:12:50: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator' ('__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' and 'int')

   12 |     int a = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, op);

      |                                                  ^
```

Comment: Seems like a `libstdc++` bug. Compiling on clang with `-stdlib=libc++` works.

Comment: This indeed works! Thank you!

Comment: BTW, trying to `#include <execution>` still fails with `-stdlib=libc++` if anyone wondered

Answer (score 1):

Actually, one of the differences between `reduce` and `accumulate` is the execution policies support. If you don't need execution policies, you can call `accumulate`. So, the code with `std::execution::seq` compiles successfully with `gcc-trunk`: https://godbolt.org/z/ERxU_q

Comment: Didn't try compiling on the trunk. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

As [@Vittorio Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo) commented, this is probably a bug or a yet to be implemented feature in `libstc++`, and it can be used by switching to `libc++` using `-libstd=libc++`